# Do hybrid classes get everything from both classes during advancement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement, class

In Pathfinder there are the hybrid classes, e.g. Arcanist, Investigator, etc. Each hybrid class has two parent classes. For example, Arcanist has Wizard and Sorcerer as parent classes.

My question is, does a hybrid class gains what is listed at the progression tables of its parents ones? For example, does Arcanist gains the bonus feats of Wizard and/or the bloodline of the Sorcerer?

I'm not referring to any extra/specific ability of the hybrid class (e.g. Exploits of the Arcanist) but if the hybrid class gets whatever is listed on the progression tables of its parent classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Only if they also appear in the hybrid class's table.**

While thematically the hybrid classes are a mix of two other classes, mechanically they are their own class and they don't get anything from any other class they don't say they get in their own description.

From [D20PFSRD, Hybrid Classes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/):

> Parent Classes: Each one of the following classes lists two classes that it draws upon to form the basis of its theme. While a character can multiclass with these parent classes, this usually results in redundant abilities. Such abilities don’t stack unless specified. [...] The new classes presented here are all hybrids of two existing core or base classes.

The fact that multiclassing with your parent class only "usually" results in redundant abilities indicates you clearly don't get all the abilities of both parent classes.  Also, if they got every ability from both parents, plus their own unique abilities, they'd completely make obsolete the parent classes - they're meant to be additional options, not the only options.